# br.readLine() for non terminating streams?

Tags: java, service, io, stream, processbuilder

I am writing a small Utility that displays a list of running/stopped services.It reads the console output and uses this output after further processing.
The program simply hangs at br.readLine() possibly because is not able to find the terminating character in the stream. Here is an excerpt from the code.

```
    try {
            String mainFile="";
            String temp="";
            Process p = Runtime
                    .getRuntime()
                    .exec(System.getenv("windir")
                            + "\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\"
                            + "powershell.exe  Get-service | Format-List name , status , displayName ");
            p.waitFor();
            InputStream i = p.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(i);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            while ((temp = br.readLine())!=null) {
                mainFile = mainFile + temp + "\n";
            }
        } catch (Exception err) {
            err.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(mainFile);
```

Unfortunately because of this problem the last syso statement is never printed.Any pointers to solve this issue ?

Comment: Have you tried [`br.ready()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#ready--) before calling `br.readLine()`? This might fix the issue.

Comment: Have tried that too with no success.